# RewriteRule with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

On my root directory of the domain example.com i've installed 
a wordpress cms like this example.com/frontend/

Then i followed the WP guide lines to load the frontend directory directly by calling the main domain.

On the root path i've the main app that is accesible only by calling a direct URL (ex. domain.com/login.php ) because if i call domain.com/login/ it's going to look for a wordpress page domain.com/frontend/login/ that doesn't exist.

I would like to ask you how to adjust my htaccess file to solve this work araound.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think installtion inside sub folder. please review link https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory
:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but it's not exactly that i need to solve.
I've already make a subfolder "frontend" where i put my wordpress cms.
and it works properly.